# Horton Stream Ordering in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, hydrology, stream-order

Is there a way to order streams using the Horton (opposed to Horton-Strahler) method in ArcGIS (10.2.2)? I know the Stream Order tool allows you to use Strahler and Shreve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe that you can perform a true Horton stream ordering using ArcGIS's **Stream Order** tool. However, the Horton stream order is essentially the same as the Strahler stream order, except that after the ordering, you need to replace each of the Strahler order values along the main trunk of the stream with the order value of the outlet. So if you can find/develop a script that identifies the main trunk of a raster stream network, you should be able to create the Horton order (if not main stem assign strahler else assign max strahler along main stem). Finding the trunk is fairly straight forward and can be accomplished by tracing the flow paths from each outlet in the raster stream network upstream. When a bifurcation is encountered, follow the tributary that has the greater flow accumulation value (larger basin size) or longest upstream length. Both are valid criteria and usually result in the same main stem except nearest the headwaters where they can differ slightly. [Here's](https://code.google.com/p/whitebox-geospatial-analysis-tools/source/browse/trunk/StreamNetworkAnalysisTools/src/plugins/FindMainStem.java) an example of code that does this if you're looking for something to base the script on. Note however that it is written in Java and not geared towards Arc scripting but it should provide good conceptual guidance. Alternatively, if you are able to use software other than ArcGIS for this task, GRASS's **r.stream.order** tool offers both Horton and Strahler stream ordering methods. These can also be used from the GRASS plugin for QGIS.